# How android application makes sure that custom external Content Provider is in place

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a scenario where I have multiple applications needs a common piece of information to be shared. I believe that a custom content provider is capable of doing this. But I could not find answers to my few questions. I'm assuming that I can have one application implement Content Provider and its permissions, and other applications just using it. I've these concerns:

1. What would happen if Content Provider application is not yet installed?
2. If application depending on Custom Content Providers are installed first, are they capable of automatically installing Custom Content provider application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an example from Google Play Services, you would have to show an error message and offer to open the play store with the app id so the user could install it.

This uri should do it

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningDetails

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```